# Tensorflow ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape when the shape of the numpy array is the same as input

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a numpy array with the shape (155508, 50).
I feed it into my TF model which is made with keras, and I get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (155508, 32) for Tensor 'dense_input_1:0', which has shape '(?, 50)'
```

I am absolutely certain the numpy array I am feeding into my model is the correct shape of (155508, 50)!

I use Keras to define my model like so:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(60, input_dim=50, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I then train it with:

```
model.fit(X.values, Y)
```

and that runs fine.

The issue occurs when I run

```
y_prediction = model.predict_proba(x_prediction)
```

I am 100% certain that my numpy array has the shape (155508, 50), so I am confused as to why the error says "shape (155508, 32)"
I confirm it in my terminal like so:

```
>>> x_prediction.shape
```

I'm starting to tear my hair out as to what could possibly make this happen.

Comment: is `x_prediction` a numpy array or pandas datatype. If it is pandas can you try `x_prediction.values` while calling `predict_proba()`

Comment: That worked! Thank you for your help, I'm new to using all of these libraries!

Comment: Glad it worked.. I wasn't so sure